# Добавление python приложения в автозагрузку

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

у меня есть простенький код. Я хочу сделать так, чтоб при нажатии на галочку в приложении оно добавлялось в автозапуске системы. То есть когда я выключу и включу компьютер, то оно должно открыться вместе системой. Как это сделать?

я ее попробовал вставить но ничего не получилось -

```
import getpass 

USER_NAME = getpass.getuser() 

def add_to_startup(file_path=""): 
    if file_path == "": 
        file_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(file)) 
        bat_path = r'C:\Users\%s\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup' % USER_NAME 

        with open(bat_path + '\\' + "open.bat", "w+") as bat_file: 
            bat_file.write(r'start "" %s' % file_path)
```

---

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(294, 346)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 90, 281, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.checkBox.setFont(font)
        self.checkBox.setObjectName("checkBox")
        self.horizontalScrollBar = QtWidgets.QScrollBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalScrollBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 330, 291, 16))
        self.horizontalScrollBar.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.horizontalScrollBar.setObjectName("horizontalScrollBar")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 160, 191, 22))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.checkBox.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Добавить в автозагрузку"))

class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: а что `Google` говорит если набрать например `вставить приложение в автозагрузку`

Comment: вот такую вещь, я ее попробовал вставить но ничего не получилось - import getpass
USER_NAME = getpass.getuser()


def add_to_startup(file_path=""):
    if file_path == "":
        file_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    bat_path = r'C:\Users\%s\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup' % USER_NAME
    with open(bat_path + '\\' + "open.bat", "w+") as bat_file:
        bat_file.write(r'start "" %s' % file_path)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Один из вариантов.

1)импортируйте модуль `os`: `import os`
2)Измените класс `ExampleApp`.

```
class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.checkBox.stateChanged.connect(self.copy_to_run)

    def copy_to_run(self):
        if self.checkBox.isChecked():
            file_path = sys.argv[0]
            file_name = file_path.split('\\')[-1]
            path = '%userprofile%\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup\\'
            os.system(f'copy "{file_path}" "{path}{file_name}"')
```

Comment: Спасибо, это работает!